# Strange C++ syntax method declaration

Tags: c++, syntax

I met this method declaration syntax in some C++ code :

```
formatted_log_t( log_level_t level, const wchar_t* msg ) : fmt(msg), level(level) {}
```

I don't understand how this is processed, the presence of ":", "fmt" & "level" before curly braces...

Comment: [Initialization lists](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Comment: Please have a look at : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: Where did you learn C++ that you've never seen this?

Comment: I'm actually learning C/C++ from scratch since one month...all apologies :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the C++ Initialization list. You can use it with class constructor example

```
class MaClasse
{
    int myInt;
    MaClasse(int value) : myInt(value) 
    {
    }
};
```

It is used to initialize member variable. It is faster to use the initialization list than use initialization in the body of the constructor